# Axis2 - No services found in this location

Tags: java, tomcat, axis, apache-axis, tomcat9

I am just trying to get a sample web service to work using Apache Tomcat 9, Axis2 and Ant.
I am following https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#introduction
and I am getting this error

[image]

and on clicking the url

[image]

Below is how my environment look like and what I have done so far.

```
C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1

C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>echo %AXIS2_HOME%
C:\javalibs\axis2-1.8.1

C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>echo %CATALINA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
```

**C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>ant generate.wsdl**
Buildfile: C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build.xml

compile.service:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build\classes
[javac] C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build.xml:42: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build\classes

generate.wsdl:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds

**C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>ant generate.service**
Buildfile: C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build.xml

compile.service:
[javac] C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build.xml:42: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

generate.service:
[copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build\classes
[jar] Building jar: C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices\build\Calculator.aar
[copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\repository\services

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

```
C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows8_OS
Volume serial number is AEA2-7F54
C:.
│   build.xml
│
├───build
│   │   Calculator.aar
│   │   Calculator.wsdl
│   │
│   └───classes
│       ├───META-INF
│       │       services.xml
│       │
│       └───Start
│               Calculator.class
│
├───resources
│   └───META-INF
│           services.xml
│
└───src
    └───Start
            Calculator.java
```

C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\git\webservices>ls C:\Users\adars\Downloads\dev\repository\services
Calculator.aar

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\services>jar -tvf Calculator.aar
     0 Sat Jun 18 18:50:46 AST 2022 META-INF/
   105 Sat Jun 18 18:50:44 AST 2022 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sat Jun 18 18:48:18 AST 2022 Start/
   525 Sat Jun 18 18:50:46 AST 2022 META-INF/services.xml
   462 Sat Jun 18 18:48:18 AST 2022 Start/Calculator.class
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<service scope="application" name="Calculator">

<description>A simple calulator to study web services</description>

<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">Start.Calculator</parameter>


-<messageReceivers>

<messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"/>

<messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"/>

</messageReceivers>

<operation name="getSum"/>

</service>
```

I copy the Calculator.aar under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\services and restart Tomcat. But I get the error *No services found in this location.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue and resolved it, and I could get the service functional.
[image]

I increased the Tomcat debug level to ALL, and it showed error

```
20-Jun-2022 20:13:11.479 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Sending application start events
20-Jun-2022 20:13:11.839 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject readObject() loading session 0CC9F9423F1AB41ADEAE13CCCB7FCCB8
20-Jun-2022 20:13:11.839 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject   loading attribute 'errprservicemap' with value '{C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\services\Calculator.aar=Error:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Start/Calculator has been **compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
```

I was compiling on a more recent version of java and Tomcat 9 could not recognize the error. I changed to Java [1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html)
But I am surprised why this is not logged at an ERROR level and instead put at a fine level. Should this be logged as a bug ?